# First time use of ruby server - Command gives no response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, server

I just set up my Ruby server, it appears successful as I am able to see the welcome page at `localhost:3000`. I am following the beginner tutorial at http://api.rubyonrails.org.

The very first command I'm asked to enter is

```
$ bin/rails generate controller welcome index
```

The terminal simply goes to the next line awaiting another command, no folders created as would be expected.  Any ideas why this would happen?  I have restarted the Server, and created a new app from scratch, any help with what could be wrong is appreciated.

Comment: Can you copy exactly everything you typed and the output?

Comment: I typed "$ bin/rails generate controller welcome index"                              There was no output, I also tried  "bin/rails generate controller welcome index" with no output and also "rails generate controller welcome index" with no output.

Comment: Try it without the "$"

Comment: The cursor simply goes to the next line awaiting another command.

Comment: When I run that command it works for me, so there has to be something else. You're typing this in terminal? Are you on Windows? Mac?

Comment: Im on a Mac, server has started and I can see the welcome screen at Localhost:3000, its as if its not recognising any commands at all

Comment: Keiths-iMac:blog Home$ rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2015-05-27 10:28:07] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-05-27 10:28:07] INFO  ruby 2.2.2 (2015-04-13) [x86_64-darwin14]
[2015-05-27 10:28:07] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=35794 port=3000
bin/rails generate controller welcome index
rails generate controller welcome index
rails server -h

Comment: This is the first time I have tried using ROR, so it has never worked correctly as of yet.

Comment: Oh, try doing it without doing rails server first. Or open a new Terminal and do it there.

Comment: Thanks again, will upvote when i get some rep up and it allows, great community!

Comment: You can actually accept answers to your own questions by hitting the green check mark -- but no hurry at all, just letting you know it's possible. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the answer from the comments here.

The problem was that the OP was trying to run the command inside of `rails server`. The fix was to either run the command in another Terminal window, or before starting the server.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `bundle exec rails controller welcome index` ? You're bundler or `env` may not be properly setup.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Wayne lue, steered me in the right direction, I'll keep in mind what you have said if i run into further issues in the tutorial.